# Getting 404 error sometimes in production environment in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, windows-8.1

I have a quiz module on my website where user take up quizzes. I have set a cache buster like this in the controller:

```
  def set_cache_buster
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
    response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
  end
```

Few users are getting random *404 error*. The users were using **Chrome** on **Windows 8.1**. Daily around 300-400 users take up the quiz and few of them sometimes get 404 error. Now its getting difficult to track the 404 issue as we get notified only for 500 errors in production and we have not faced this issue in local or test environment. And my concern is, if this was a code issue then all the users should have got it as there are more than 30,000 users. Any idea why this is happening to only few of the users?

**Adding more info:**
Its not related to any link, it just happens randomly. Its like we have 3 attempts for the user to clear the quiz. Few who get error we ask them to avail the left over attempts and attempt the quiz and they are able to. Most of the time it works fine only. Other users have already completed the quiz where few report 404 for the same quiz.
For example: In the exam module the questions are loaded one by one.
So first the user goes to: `exam_instructions/some_quiz`. Then the user is redirect to the quiz page where I have a form which is like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:action=> "calc_score",:id => @quiz.slug, :name => 'question'},:method => :post,:id=>'form',:name=>'question') do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The user submits and the form data goes to **calc_score** with the **quiz id**. The score gets calculated:

```
before_filter :find_quiz

def calc_score
  #Calculates the score for the current question
  # redirects to the show page with the quiz id where the next question is presented to the user on the show page
  redirect_to :action=> "show", :id=> @quiz.slug
end

def show
#next question is loaded
end

protected
def find_quiz
 @quiz = Quiz.find_by_slug(params[:id]) or raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) if params[:id]
end
```

Now when the users are taking up the quiz suddenly after submitting a quiz they see 404 error. Now if the **@quiz** object was **nil** the show page itself would not have loaded but it was present. Only on submission something goes wrong for few users which changes the **:id to undefined** or it is **nil** and the user see's a 404 error page where 100's of user have already completed the same quiz.

Comment: Check the log files related to the IP , as you haven't provided much details to debug and know the cause

Comment: debug level is set to _:warn_ @CaffeineCoder.

Comment: You're going to need to store data about the 404s somewhere in order to identify the problem here.  What is your http server?  (ie nginx, apache etc)  This should have an access log, but there may not be enough info in there for you to diagnose the problems.    You could change your notification setup so that you get notified of the 404s as well.  Are you **sure** that this problem is only affecting Windows 8.1+Chrome users?

Comment: Also, what makes you think the 404 error is anything to do with the headers that you list?  Does the 404 always occur when accessing a particular url or path?  If so, what is it?  Basically you need to add a load more info to your question in order to try to diagnose this awkward-sounding bug.

Comment: It is nginx, and yes till now the users who reported the issue were on Windows 8.1, Chrome. And if I change the debug_level to _:debug_ then the log file is going to be flooded as there are too many users accessing the website.

Comment: have you tried to setup exception_notification gem? it has 404 notifications support https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/pull/260

Comment: Thanks @EugeneM. We had this gem but code for Active Record was commented so I uncommented it and have pushed the changes to production, I just have to wait to get a mail with this kind of error.

Comment: Great, it is interesting to know if the issue is caused by the particular version of Chrome or not. Recently faced the issue that Chrome v.42 vs .40 on both OS X and Windows has the changed behavior for large sized inline data that just causes the blank screen with no errors or messages.

Comment: Will update this thread once I get a mail notification for this type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally sorted out the issue was able to track it with the help of the 404 notifications as suggested by @EugeneM. There was a variable which was named incorrectly which only got triggered under certain circumstances. The notification made it easier to track the bug. Thanks @EugeneM.